# Failed to execute bash commands using python

Tags: python, bash, os.system

I would like to run bash commands using a python function as follows :

```
def ExtractData(data, type_list):

    for i in type_list :

        os.system("sed -n '/\t{}\t/p' {} > raw_extract_{}.tsv".format(i, data, i))
        os.system("cut -d$'\t' -f2,4,8,46,63,65,66 raw_extract_{}.tsv > extract_{}_reduced.tsv".format(i, i))

    return "Done !"


ExtractData("data.tsv", [2201, 2202])
```

However, even if the "sed" part worked fine, I got no result with the "cut" commands, it returned an exit status 1. I tried to type it myself in the console and I got the expected result, so the commands are correct. Can someone see what is wrong with this program ?

Ps : I know `os.system` is deprecated, I tried `subprocess.call` as well but I got the exact same error.

Comment: Have you considered just doing these operations in Python using, e.g., the csv module?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use bash in order to process my files faster since they're pretty big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python uses `/bin/sh` by default to execute commands. Running your second command there produced the following error message for me:

> cut: the delimiter must be a single character
>   Try 'cut --help' for more information.

In `cut`, the default delimiter is `\t`, so try running the following command instead:

```
cut -f2,4,8,46,63,65,66 raw_extract_{}.tsv > extract_{}_reduced.tsv
```

Alternatively, you can use the command

```
/bin/bash -c "cut -d$'\t' -f2,4,8,46,63,65,66 raw_extract_{}.tsv > extract_{}_reduced.tsv"
```

Comment: Deleting the delimiter fixed it, thank you for that quick answer !

Comment: @Aegir no problem, you should try it with the `subprocess` module again, the problem was probably the same, and that way you won't be using a deprecated function :)

Comment: You're right, now it works fine with subprocess.call as well !